# Mansions of Madness - Loss of Vision

Tags: mansions-of-madness

With the "Loss of Vision" mythos card, can the keeper play additional mythos cards that require the investigator to be in a room with darkness for any room that investigator is in?

I interpreted as yes, but only effecting that specific investigator though it's caused some debate amongst our group.

We'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: Hi there, could you provide the exact wording on the "Loss of Vision" card please?

Comment: The wording is: "Whenever you explore, treat the room as if it were in darkness."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording of the card is:

> Whenever you **explore**, treat the room as if it were in darkness.

(Empahsis mine)

Normally, darkness forces you to spend a **movement** step in addition to the regular **action** step to explore and to also receive **-2** to attribute tests in combat. This card just makes it so that whenever you explore, you apply the penalty of spending an additional **movement** step.

This trauma doesn't affect combat. If the player with the trauma is not exploring, penalty doesnt apply.

Either way, the room is technically **not in darkness**.

Based on this, I would rule it as invalid as playing a card that required a room to be in darkness.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but based on the qualifier does that mean the only detriment to the effected player is the move+explore action for exploring?

Comment: Yes. I've clarified my answer